# How to create network map on c#?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, network-programming

I am trying to create network map on c# like on this image
[image]
I have searched in google a lot but can't find any library or code sample. I only found ways to do [broadcasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  on network or [get computers names](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx) on my domain. But what I need is to get all computers on my network with their names, IP addresses and OSes like in picture. Is there any libraries to this in .Net? There are lots of apps which can do this, some of them are free but no one is open source.
Thanks.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: @Yahia I tryed [UDP bradcasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1(v=VS.100).aspx) and [Retreiving a list of network computer names using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx). All samples I found were like these two.

Comment: and what is not working (second link) ?

Comment: Everything is working fine, but as you can see there is only names of computers, no OS info, no connection schema between them.

Comment: what is it you want to create ? a monitoring package ?

Comment: That will the next step. But first I whant to get network map. After that I will try to create  monitoring package.

Comment: Is a commercial library/component an option ?

Comment: I am planning to make this project open source, so I think no.

Comment: please see my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comments above:

One good approach is to use SNMP for this kind of stuff... there are commercial and free libraries for this... since you want that to be free just the opensource ones (checkout whether the license is compatible with the license you are planning to use):

- http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/
- http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/ and/or http://code.google.com/p/sharpsnmplib/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/snmpsharpnet/

As per comments:

Docs and examples for snmpsharpnet can be found [here](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/6) and [here](http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/9).

Comment: Is there any tutorial for snmpsharpnet? I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @SamvelSiradeghyan check these links out: http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/6 and http://www.snmpsharpnet.com/node/9 . HTH